# How to copy full path from Terminal in Mac OS

Tags: macos, terminal, path

I want to copy path of one file, but the directory isn't open in Finder, it is opened in terminal. Is it possible by invocation `<utility> filename` to copy full file path string to the Mac OS clipboard? Like copying the output of the following command there.

```
`pwd`/filename
```

Added the following line to my `.zshrc`

```
function cn { echo -n $(pwd)/$1 | pbcopy }
```

Just aliasing don't work because of arguments. Exact same string should work in bash too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
echo $(pwd)/filename | pbcopy
```

This will give you a non-quoted and non-escaped string, which, depending on your use case, may not work properly when pasted elsewhere.

Comment: `pbcopy` is just what I need, will accept this answer as soon it will become possible, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to install *greadlink* with brew: `brew install coreutils`, you could implement a solution that works for any path (file in another folder or a folder name).
This is what I have in ~/.zshrc:

```
function path_to_clipboard() {
    local path_escaped="$(printf "%q\n" "$1")"
    local path_escaped_full=$(greadlink -f "$path_escaped")
    echo -n $path_escaped_full | pbcopy
}
alias pb=path_to_clipboard
```